# jsPDF export to pdf with style

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am trying to export the div content to PDF using jsPDF

```js
function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
    // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
    source = $('#customers')[0];

    // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
    // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
    // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
    // (class, of compound) at this time.
    specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
    // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
        //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    }, margins);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="customers">
<div class="container">
        <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
                    <div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
                </div>
                <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body">
                    <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>
                    <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            @*<input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="username or email" />*@
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                            @*<input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password" />*@
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    Remember me
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                            <!-- Button -->
                            <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                <a id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success">Login  </a>
                                <a id="btn-fblogin" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Facebook</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12 control">
                                <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%">
                                    Don't have an account!
                                    <a href="#" onClick="$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#signupbox').show()">
                                        Sign Up Here
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table id="tab_customers" class="table table-striped">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="20%">
                <col width="20%">
                    <col width="20%">
                        <col width="20%">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr class='warning'>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Population</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Chinna</td>
                <td>1,363,480,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>19.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>India</td>
                <td>1,241,900,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>17.4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>317,746,000</td>
                <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                <td>4.44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Indonesia</td>
                <td>249,866,000</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>3.49</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>201,032,714</td>
                <td>July 1, 2013</td>
                <td>2.81</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML();">PDF</button>
```

I tried with **html2canvas** http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js but no luck so can some one help me. I used this http://jsfiddle.net/cdmgmfqf/386/ but on the output I am getting button and some black background

I did one more try but the same issue

http://jsfiddle.net/DorababuMeka/Luhy8bzf/